# Iframe version of nicEdit not working on IE8 and IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, nicedit

I really need the nicEdit's iframe version working for IE8 and IE9.
But the problem is that for IE8 the editor is not editable and for IE9 it says that addEvent() is not defined for the element.

Please help!

Comment: I am extremely sorry to disappoint anyone who needed an answer to this Question. I did some searching and concluded that the use designMode on iframe in IE is a risky business.Also that there was something about the document of the iframe being non accessable as the document.domain was not same as that for the parent. I ended up using the normal version for the time. Ill definately post back if i get the definate ans.